# SWI-Prolog: splitting text atom into list of characters

Tags: string, split, prolog

Very simple question: I know there are plenty of ways to split an atom, eg 'example atom' on some delimiter, eg ' ' -> ['example', 'atom'] but is there a way to split up every character? Eg ['e', 'x', 'a', ... 'o', 'm']. I've tried

```
atomic_list_concat(List, '', Atom),
```

but that generates the error

```
ERROR: atomic_list_concat/3: Domain error: `non_empty_atom' expected, found `'
```

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atom_chars/2

```
?- atom_chars(hello, X).
X = [h, e, l, l, o].
```

Comment: Perfect! Obviously I'm just terrible at googling. Thanks.

Comment: @Boris - I'm well aware. I must have just missed it. I'm still new to prolog, and sometimes it can be difficult to know what you're looking for when you're unfamiliar with the terminology.

Comment: @EmmetOT please remember to mark the answer as accepted if this is the solution that you were looking for.