# Prolog - split word into separate letters

Tags: prolog

[Follow up to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478457/swi-prolog-splitting-text-atom-into-list-of-characters). How could I split the word into letters without using lists or built-in predicate `atom_chars/2.`

Something along the lines of `split_word(Word, Letter, Rest).`

Where Letter would be 1st letter of the word.

I'm having difficulties splitting string and I don't know how to utilize `''` as "splitter". To get an inspiration I tried checking source code of `atom_chars/2` with `predicate_property(atom_char(_,_), P).` where I got to the source, but in the file I didn't find anything useful.

Help appreciated.

Comment: You're making this more complicated than it really is. The answer to this is almost done based upon the answer to the question you linked. `atom_chars/2` gives the correspondence between an atom or string and a list of characters. All you need to do at that point is: `split_word(Word, Letter, Rest) :- atom_chars(Word, [Letter|Rest]).`

Comment: I know how to solve it with atom_chars/2. The thing is I will have a closed book exam of prolog and without googling I would never know of this built-in predicate.

Comment: I hope it helps! I compiled my comments into an answer and have removed my original comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "splitting a string into atoms" I assume you mean more specifically "splitting a string into a list of characters".

First, we need to distinguish *strings* versus *atoms. In Prolog, a *string* as denoted with double quotes is normally a list of character codes, whereas an *atom* as denoted with single quotes, or a name starting with a lower case letter, is a symbol. See [What is the difference between ' and " in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264699/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-prolog). Here's what it looks like in GNU Prolog:

```
| ?- X = "abc".  % A string of characters

X = [97,98,99]

yes
| ?- X = 'abc'.  % An atom

X = abc

yes
| ?- X = abc.    % An atom

X = abc

yes
| ?- X = 'Abc'.  % An atom

X = 'Abc'

yes
| ?-
```

So, if you want to get the head and rest of a list of character codes from a string, it's as simple as unifying them:

```
| ?- "abcd" = [H | T].

H = 97
T = [98,99,100]

yes
| ?-
```

On the other hand, if you want to do this with an *atom*, then you need first to convert the atom to character codes using `atom_chars/2`:

```
| ?- atom_chars(abc, [H|T]).

H = a
T = [b,c]

yes
| ?-
```

In SWI Prolog, they've allowed the use of double quotes to represent an integral string without it representing a list of character codes. It is not, though, the same as an atom. See [Why has the representation of double quoted text changed?](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ext-dquotes-motivation). Here are some queries in SWI Prolog:

```
1 ?- "abc" = 'abc'.
false.

2 ?- X = "abc".
X = "abc".

3 ?- "abc" = [H|T].
false.

4 ?- atom_chars("abc", [H|T]).
H = a,
T = [b, c].

5 ?- atom_chars(abc, [H|T]).
H = a,
T = [b, c].
```

Oddly, `"abc"` is not the same as the atom `abc` (as seen by the failing unification), but `atom_chars/2` treats `"abc"` the same as it would the atom, `abc`.

Prolog has flags that affect its behavior. In SWI Prolog specifically, there is the `double_quotes` flag, whose value can  be modified so that the double quote representation behaves in the traditional Prolog sense, as shown in the GNU Prolog example above.

Back to the problem at hand, atom processing predicates are fairly fundamental to Prolog, so it's good to know the basic ones by heart if you need to do atom processing in a closed-book exam.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand, you don't want to use `atom_chars/2` but it's ok to use other built-in predicates. You can use `sub_string/5` and `string_length/2` to solve the problem in this way in SWI Prolog:

```
split(_,0).
split(S,Len):-
    Len > 0,
    Len1 is Len-1,
    sub_string(S,0,1,_,Sub), %get the first letter
    writeln(Sub),
    sub_string(S,1,Len1,_,Sub1), %get the rest of the string
    split(Sub1,Len1).

solve(S):-
    string_length(S,Len),
    split(S,Len).

?- solve("abcd").
a
b
c
b
true
```

Comment: I did kind of awkwardly phrase that. What I would like to know is the mechanism of splitting a string into atoms. So basically if there is something like what lists are using [Head|Tail], but for strings.